# go install command with glide on windows

Tags: go, glide-golang

I'm having trouble running the go install $(glide nv) command.
I run this command from within my project's folder within the src folder of the go workspace directoy

so basically I do :

```
%GOPATH%/src/my/project/ go install $(glide nv)
```

The error message I get is as follow :

```
can't load package: package $(glide: cannot find package "$(glide" in any of:            
        C:\Go\src\$(glide (from $GOROOT)                                                 
        W:\GO_WORKSPACE\src\$(glide (from $GOPATH)                              
can't load package: package nv): cannot find package "nv)" in any of:                    
        C:\Go\src\nv) (from $GOROOT)                                                     
        W:\GO_WORKSPACE\src\nv) (from $GOPATH)
```

I had previously run glide install without a problem on that project.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$(...)` is a shell command substitution, you can't use that in windows cmd.exe.

Comment: @JimB thanks! What would you suggest I do on windows to make this work ? Thanks.

Comment: No idea, I don't use windows. Searching for `windows "command substitution"` seems to bring up some results.

Answer (score 0):

It works on powershell. At the project directory run command:

```
go install $(glide nv)
```